# How to remove pattern of number with a specific character and keep only the number?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python with regex and I have a question to remove the pattern of string contain numbers with a specific character for example we have a pattern like this: 1234" with a special character " and I want to keep only 1234 by removing the " from those numbers.

Here is what I detect for that pattern:

```
s = re.sub(r'[0-9]+\"','',s)
```

The question is how can I put in ' ' to get the numbers I want back if we keep ' ' sure it will remove the number also not only the ".

Desire result:

```
s = 1234
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is the special character always at the end?

Comment: yes it is. like 12345" and I want to keep only 12345

Comment: `s[:-1]` should be enough for the pattern.

Comment: Can you write in the re.sub(..)? because I need to always detect the pattern digit" and keep digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the matched pattern and use it (while specifically for your case `s[:-1]` also works):

```
re.sub(r'([0-9]+)\"','\\1',s)
```

Comment: Why we also put (..) for that pattern?

Comment: You need to get the digits in digits" to obtain just digits.

Comment: I have this string for example 

```[{"id" : 645042","begin": 33,"end": 46,"entity": "New York City","text": "New York City","score": 0.40,"categories" : ["New York City","Cities in New York","Former capitals of the United States","Former United States state capitals","Government of New York City","Metropolitan areas of New York","Populated places established in 1624","Populated places on the Hudson River","Port cities and towns of the United States Atlantic coast","1624 establishments in the Thirteen Colonies","Article Feedback 5 Additional Articles"]}]```

Comment: And I want to remove the “ from the value of key “id” but here I see that the phrase "Populated places established in 1624" also remove the “ after 1624 which I don’t want to happen how I can overcame this?

Comment: So, `s` here is `d['id']` where `d` is the dictionary. I don't see how it replaces the phrase. Your original question however is answered.

Comment: Can you give me some ideas how to detect this for example detect the pattern "id" : 645042" and replace it with only "id" : 645042?

Comment: It is advised to not have any follow up questions. Please try and research on your own. I bet you could find similar questions or help online. If not, please post a new question with all details to avoid a state like this.

Comment: Okay I will ask a new question.

Comment: @Erwinwin I would first parse the JSON, then work work with the parsed structure.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Can you purpose a solution?

Comment: @Erwinwin Where is this string coming from? I just noticed that the JSON is malformed. The best option would be to find out where the JSON gets malformed and fix the issue there. Instead of first malforming it and than patching it with a band ait.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

a = "1234 extra text"
numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', a)
s = int(numbers[0])
print("s = ",s)
```

Output:

```
s = 12345
```

You will get numbers as a list. If there are multiple int vales separated by characters they will be stored in the list.
eg:

```py
a = "1234 34"
numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', a)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['1234','34']
```

Comment: I think you missed understand my question. Ex: I have a string 12345" avec special character " I want to keep only 12345

Comment: Even if you have a string as a = ' 12345" ' then also the output will be 12345.